# What happens to custom vehicles if the impound lot is full?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I found (stole) a tow truck, and tow trucks are awesome so I went and got it upgraded, resprayed, etc. I was going to go store it in my garage when there was a random event with some dudes robbing a store. I tried to shoot them, but got shot myself.

Upon returning to the store, the tow truck was gone. I checked the impound only to find two other cars in there. Is there any hope of finding my tow truck? One of the impounded cars wasn't even my car (I never bought or customized it). Is there a way to make it so stolen cars (unwanted) will not be impounded?

I am playing on the PC.

Comment: Did you place a tracker on the car?

Comment: I  thought trackers were only for online. If I had, would it not have dissapeared?

Comment: if you stored/ placed a tracker the game would have made the car essential and part of the story so it would get impounded not vanish. Also regarding your impound prevention there is no such thing and/or way

Comment: A note here, when you get to the random event of people robbing a store, don't kill them. If you save them, one of them will become available for use during heists.

Comment: I couldn't pick them up in the tow truck (only 2 seats) and I didn't want to go steal another car so I ran one of them over and the other shot me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GTA Online, vehicles will only save if you attached a tracker to it at a Mod Shop. Without a tracker, the game thinks it's just another car that you stole and it will not save it. There is no way to get that vehicle again, so you're going to have to find another tow truck.

It is also impossible to prevent a car from getting impounded. If you get a wanted level in a vehicle and die soon after exiting the vehicle, the police assume it is yours and will impound it.

Comment: Can a tracker be attached to vehicles in singleplayer?

Comment: @galacticninja According to the comments under the question: **Yes, it can**

Comment: @Alex Searching for '[gta v tracker singleplayer](https://www.google.com/search?q=gta+v+tracker+singleplayer)' only shows me pages where it says that it *can't* be done in singleplayer. If this is untrue, how would you attach a tracker in singleplayer? (Can't seem to find a tracker mod in LS Customs.)